# Ninefold devotion?

Tags: shiva, tantra, bhakti, shakti, kaulam

In 39th verse, 17th Ullasah of Kaularnava Tantra, Shiva defines Purana to divine mother:

> पुण्यपापादिकथनादाक्षसादिनिवारणात् ।
> **नवभक्त्यादिजननात्** पुराण इति कथ्यते ।। ३६।।

> **Purana:** Because it tells of merit and demerit (punyapapa ). because it dispels evil beings like rākṣasas, and because it generates **ninefold devotion (navabhakti )** and the like, it is called purana.।।39।।

What is ninefold devotion here, he is talking about?

Comment: See this: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/navavidhabhakti

Comment: The commentator of the Kularnava Tantram copy that I have explains what are the Navavidha Bhaktis under the verse. Something that is mostly talked about in (Vaishnava) Puranas.

Comment: @Rickross seems right. You may post an answer with relevant verses in referenced sources.

Comment: @Rickross ...wait! Do you mean this ninefold devotion could be later addition and not really part of Kaularnava?

Comment: No I don't mean that .. I have used this verse earlier to show that Puranas are basically Bhakti Mulak scriptures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Navavidha Bhakti are nine types of devotional services. It is usually referred to in connection with Lord Vishnu only.

Mentioned in the [Bhagavata Purana 7.5.23-24](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/5/23-24/):

> श्रीप्रह्राद उवाच श्रवणं कीर्तनं विष्णो: स्मरणं पादसेवनम् ।
>  अर्चनं
> वन्दनं दास्यं सख्यमात्मनिवेदनम् ॥ २३ ॥
>  इति पुंसार्पिता विष्णौ
> भक्तिश्चेन्नवलक्षणा ।
>  क्रियेत भगवत्यद्धा तन्मन्येऽधीतमुत्तमम् ॥ २४
> ॥
>
> śrī-prahrāda uvāca
>
> śravaṇaṁ kīrtanaṁ viṣṇoḥ
>  smaraṇaṁ pāda-sevanam
>  arcanaṁ
> vandanaṁ dāsyaṁ
>  sakhyam ātma-nivedanam
>  iti puṁsārpitā
> viṣṇau
>  bhaktiś cen nava-lakṣaṇā
>  kriyeta bhagavaty addhā
> tan manye ’dhītam uttamam
>
> **Synonyms**
>
> śrī-prahrādaḥ uvāca — Prahlāda Mahārāja said; śravaṇam — hearing;
> kīrtanam — chanting; viṣṇoḥ — of Lord Viṣṇu (not anyone else);
> smaraṇam — remembering; pāda-sevanam — serving the feet; arcanam —
> offering worship (with ṣoḍaśopacāra, the sixteen kinds of
> paraphernalia); vandanam — offering prayers; dāsyam — becoming the
> servant; sakhyam — becoming the best friend; ātma-nivedanam —
> surrendering everything, whatever one has; iti — thus; puṁsā arpitā —
> offered by the devotee; viṣṇau — unto Lord Viṣṇu (not to anyone else);
> bhaktiḥ — devotional service; cet — if; nava-lakṣaṇā — possessing nine
> different processes; kriyeta — one should perform; bhagavati — unto
> the Supreme Personality of Godhead; addhā — directly or completely;
> tat — that; manye — I consider; adhītam — learning; uttamam — topmost.
>
> **Translation**
>
> Prahlāda Mahārāja said: Hearing and chanting about the transcendental
> holy name, form, qualities, paraphernalia and pastimes of Lord Viṣṇu,
> remembering them, serving the lotus feet of the Lord, offering the
> Lord respectful worship with sixteen types of paraphernalia, offering
> prayers to the Lord, becoming His servant, considering the Lord one’s
> best friend, and surrendering everything unto Him (in other words,
> serving Him with the body, mind and words) — these nine processes are
> accepted as pure devotional service. One who has dedicated his life to
> the service of Kṛṣṇa through these nine methods should be understood
> to be the most learned person, for he has acquired complete knowledge.